# Socket IO socket client getting disconnected

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am making a game with NODE JS and socket iO

In my main file (index.js) when a person connects and logs in I add them into my player pool as an object. Within the player object I store their socket so when they are in the game I can emit events to them real time

```
 var index ={};
 index.playerPool = [];
```

adding player

```
        socket.on("user_information",function(info){
    //when the user sends me their user information lets create a new player object. 
       checkIfPlayerExistsInMap(info.user_id);

        var player =  new playa.playa();
        player.name = info.name;
        player.picture = info.picture;
        player.email = info.email;
        player.user_id = info.user_id;
        player.socket = socket;
```

adding player to game

```
        var ngame = new game.game();
        var id = getNewGameId();
        p.current_game_id = id;
        ngame.created = id;
        index.currentGames[String(id)] = ngame;
        var ng = index.currentGames[String(id)];
        ng.addPlayer(p);
```

This works fine through out my game (for about 4 min). All of a sudden, when I emit a certain event, my reference to the player.socket will no longer work.

I tried to log the object I get the following

```
 connected: false,
 disconnected: true,
```

Is there a reason that my socket IO client is getting disconnected? I keep sending my clients data randomly (IE I have a lobby countdown timer and a notification when the game starts which works great), how ever when a player looses I can no longer emit an event to any of my clients and I find this very strange?

versions:

```
    {
    "name": "socket-chat-example",
     "version": "0.0.1",
     "description": "my first socket.io app",
     "dependencies": {
      "express": "~4.8.7",
     "socket.io": "~1.0.6"
  }
}
```

I originally thought that it had to do with the fact that I had an interval function running on my clients... but when I took them out the problem still persisted

I also tried a call back function to the socket who emitted the "player lost event"... Then and only then did my socket emit an event. I also tried an io. emit just to make sure that my clients were connected at all.. which worked.

So I am figuring that the reference doesn't get held in my object correctly?

Has anyone had any experience with this?

this is how I try to emit my event in the game class

```
        var p = index.index.playerPool[String(my_id)];
        p.socket.emit("player_left",player_id_leaving);
```

which again works for the lobby count down and notifying players that other players have left etc before the game starts.

Comment: @Ravi added  all relevant code